# Input buffer not clearing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am encoutering a problem with cin object of c++. I currently use microsoft visual studio 2013 ultimate edition as my IDE.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char inp[20], inp2;
    cout<<"input\t";
    cin>>inp;
    cout<<"input char";
    inp2=getchar();
    cout<<inp<<endl<<inp2;
}
```

the problem is after reading input from first cin line getchar is reading a new liine charector. i.e cin leaves a new line charecter in buffer after it is done taking an input. getchar reads that nw line charector so it doesnt take any input from user at all.

Comment: This is expected behavior. What's your question?

Comment: Also... "microsoft visual studio 2013 ultimate edition" would be your IDE, not compiler. Regardless, doesn't appear to be any bugs in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first input is processed, you can use `cin.ignore()` to ignore the rest of the line.

```
cin>>inp;

// Ignore the rest of the line.
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout<<"input char";
inp2=getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional `getchar` after `cin >> inp` to read the newline. Then the logic of the code below will be right.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take all input from user at all, like reading an entire line

```
std::string input, input2;
std::cout<<"input\t";
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

maybe worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gets()` to read in the string. Using another `getchar()` is not a good coding practice:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char inp[20],inp2;
    cout<<"input\t";
    gets(inp);
    cout<<"input char";
    inp2=getchar();
    cout<<inp<<endl<<inp2;
}
```